# Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null for ckeditor angularjs2

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I am getting this error when I load ckeditor.
I have import ng2-ckeditor and also into a directive.
loaded a js fileusinf belove code.

```
window['CKEDITOR_BASEPATH'] = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/';
require('ckeditor');
```

Still I am getting error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null